# prove or disprove $\ln{(1+x^2)}\cdot\ln{(1+y^2)}\ge \ln^2{(1+xy)}$

Tags: inequality

let $x,y>0$.prove or disprove
$$\ln{(1+x^2)}\cdot\ln{(1+y^2)}\ge \ln^2{(1+xy)}$$

By this inequality it seem Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$(1+x^2)(1+y^2)\ge (1+xy)^2$$
But this is Log function.so How to prove it? Thanks

Comment: First step: Make a plot and realize it's actually $\le$. So you can easily disprove your statement by finding a couterexample ;) The hard part is of course proving the true statement.

Comment: Maybe  did you mean the following. Let $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$. Prove that: $\ln(1-x^2)\ln(1-y^2)\geq\ln^2(1-xy).$ It's true and nice.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg From your comment and a buncha plots, I now think it holds that $\log(1+ax^2)\log(1+ay^2) \le \log(1+axy)^2$ for all $a>0$ and the reverse inequality holds for $a<0$. This generalizes both your statement and the reverse of the OP. Do you have a hint or a reference for proving any of this? I'm coming up with nothing.

Comment: counterexample x=1 y=2

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that the inequality is not correct.

Putting $y=\frac 1x$ we get,

$$\ln{\left(1+x^2\right)}\times\ln{\left(1+\frac {1}{x^2}\right)}\ge \ln^2{2}$$

But,

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\ln {\left(1+x^2\right)}\times \ln {\left(1+\frac {1}{x^2}\right)}\right)=0<\ln ^2 2.\end{align}$$

---

**Evaluation of the limit:**

Let, $1+x^2=e^u$. This implies, $1+\frac{1}{x^2}=1+\frac{1}{e^u-1}.$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\ln {\left(1+x^2\right)}\times \ln {\left(1+\frac {1}{x^2}\right)}\right)
&=\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(u\times \ln {\left(1+\frac {1}{e^u-1}\right)}\right)\\
&=\lim_{u\to\infty }\frac{\ln {\left(1+\frac {1}{e^u-1}\right)}}{\frac 1u}\\
&=\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{-\frac{1}{e^u-1}}{-\frac {1}{u^2}}\\
&=\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{u^2}{e^u-1}\\
&=2\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{u}{e^u}\\
&=0.\end{align}$$

---

But, we can calculate the limit faster.

Using the inequality,

$$\ln (1+u)<u, ~u>0$$

We have,

$$\begin{align}0&\le\ln\left(1+x^2\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\\
&\le\ln\left(\left(1+x\right)^2\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\\
&=2\ln\left(1+x\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\\
&\le \frac{2x}{x^2}\\
&=\frac{2}{x}\end{align}$$

and $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac 2x=0.$$

Then, the [Squeeze theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) tells us that,

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\ln {\left(1+x^2\right)}\times \ln {\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}\right)=0<\ln ^2 2.\end{align}$$

---

This effective solution using the Squeeze theorem was made by [@BarryCipra](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/86747/barry-cipra).

Since I found this method nicer and more useful, I added this to my answer.

Comment: The limit as $x\to\infty$ is correct? How? Because $\ln(1+x^2)$ doesn't tend to $0$...

Answer (score 3):

The reverse is true:

> **Problem**: Let $x, y > 0$. Prove that
> $\ln(1 + x^2) \ln(1 + y^2) \le \ln^2(1 + xy)$.

*Proof*:

With the substitutions $x = \mathrm{e}^{u/2}$ and $y = \mathrm{e}^{v/2}$,
taking logarithm, it suffices to prove that
$$\ln \ln (1 + \mathrm{e}^{u}) + \ln \ln (1 + \mathrm{e}^{v})
\le 2 \ln \ln (1 + \mathrm{e}^{(u + v)/2})$$
which is true since
$g(w) = \ln \ln (1 + \mathrm{e}^{w})$ is concave:
$$g''(w) = -\frac{ \mathrm{e}^{w}( \mathrm{e}^{w} - \ln(1 + \mathrm{e}^{w}))}{(1 + \mathrm{e}^{w})^2\ln^2(1 + \mathrm{e}^{w} )} < 0$$
where $\mathrm{e}^{w} - \ln(1 + \mathrm{e}^{w}) > 0$ is easy to prove by taking derivative.

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

(This is wrong. Leaving this up here for now in case someone tries this approach.)

**Hint:** Your CS inequality demonstrates that

$$\ln (1+x^2) + \ln (1+y^2) \geq 2 \ln (1+xy).$$

Now apply AM-GM to $ \ln (1+x^2) \times \ln (1+y^2)$.
However, that doesn't work. We get:

$$ \ln (1+x^2) \times \ln (1+y^2) \leq \left( \frac{ \ln (1+x^2) + \ln (1+y^2) } { 2 } \right)^2 \geq \left( \ln ( 1+xy) \right)^2$$

Comment: No, I had the same idea, but CS works in the wrong direction. And AM-GM on the LHS overshoots the mark.

Comment: @Milten Ah yes. Hm.